# Свой layout в QMdiSubWindow

Tags: c++, qt, виджет

Как можно поставить свой `QGridLayout` в окно, наследующее от `QMdiSubWindow`? Попытка простого `setLayout()` выдаёт ворнинг, мол окно уже имеет свой layout.

UPD: Методом проб и ошибок пришёл к тому, что создаю экземпляр `QFrame` и ставлю его методом `setWidget()` как внутренний виджет окна, а уже на этот фрейм цепляю лейаут. Это правильный подход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно либо пользоваться имеющимся лейаутом, либо в этот лэйаут вставить самый обыкновенный пустой виджет (expanding по горизонтали и вертикали) через `setWidget` и в этот виджет вставить ваш `QGridLayout`.

Comment: А как использовать имеющийся? Вот мне нужно будет расположить десяток элементов по сетке.

Comment: @Artik, на самом деле не надо использовать имеющийся слой, т.к. он предназначен для размещения панели инструментов, меню и, собственно, самого вставляемого виджета. В остальном, @Matty права: должен быть задействован метод `setWidget()`, в который вставляем пустой `QWidget`, и уже в свою очередь на него вешаем слой-сетку - `QGridLayout`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!